# How to make zeros white in R ggplot heatmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm working on a heatmap where my values range from 0-40 and I'd like to have my 0s be colored white while the other values from 1-40 are colored with a gradient. I've experimented with a few options but none seem to accomplish exactly what I'm hoping to do.

The code below is the closest I've been able to get, where I set the limits for the scale fill gradient to 1-40, but this makes 0s appear gray not white:

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar, fill=n)) +
          geom_tile(color="white", size = 0.25) +
          geom_text(aes(label = n)) +
          scale_fill_gradient(low="gold", high="darkorchid", limits=c(1, 40))
```

Is there a way to somehow combine scale_fill_manual and scale_fill_gradient to achieve this? Or is there a completely different function I can try?

Thanks!

Comment: Change your 0s to `NA` and use `scale_fill_gradient(..., na.value = "white")` (or maybe the `limits = c(1, 40)` will already make them `NA` and you just need the `na.value` specification)

Comment: Thanks! But in some of my heatmap columns all the values are zero, and won't changing them to NA's end up excluding that whole column?

Comment: No, it won't do that. If you share a reproducible example, I can demonstrate. If you try it and still need help, that is.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're right, this worked! Will post my final code below.

Answer (score 1):

I used Gregor Thomas's suggestion and created a new variable called "n_nas" where I coded my zeros as NA. I used "n_nas" as the fill but used the original "n" variable for the labels so that they still appeared as zeros in the heatmap. Here is my final code:

```
dataframe$n_nas <- ifelse(dataframe$n==0,NA,dataframe$n)

ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=xvar, y=yvar, fill=n_nas)) +
          geom_tile(color="white", size = 0.25) +
          geom_text(aes(label = n)) + 
          scale_fill_gradient(low="gold", high="darkorchid", na.value="white"))
```

Thanks!